# In this ajax i can't get the url response! how to solve this errors?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnLoad').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/ajaxGetQuoteJSON.jsp?symbol=tatasteel',
                //data: '{"name":"jonas"}', // or JSON.stringify ({name: 'jonas'}),
               success: function (data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
               contentType: "application/json",
               dataType: 'script',
               error: function () {
                      alert("error");
               }
       });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was debugging it and got this error on your jsp return:

> ajaxGetQuoteJSON.jsp?symbol=tatasteel&_=1479470488715:11 Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Here's the return, but since it has JSON syntax errors, JavaScript is not able to handle it. Can you fix this?

```
{"futLink":"\/live_market\/dynaContent\/live_watch\/get_quote\/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=TATASTEEL&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=24NOV2016&type=-&strike=-","otherSeries":["EQ"],"lastUpdateTime":"18-NOV-2016 16:00:12","tradedDate":"18NOV2016","data":[{"extremeLossMargin":"5.00","cm_ffm":"25,807.04","bcStartDate":"30-JUL-16","change":"-7.75","buyQuantity3":"-","sellPrice1":"-","buyQuantity4":"-","sellPrice2":"-","priceBand":"No Band","buyQuantity1":"403","deliveryQuantity":"4,52,706","buyQuantity2":"-","sellPrice5":"-","quantityTraded":"46,60,147","buyQuantity5":"-","sellPrice3":"-","sellPrice4":"-","open":"390.05","low52":"211.15","securityVar":"11.84","marketType":"N","pricebandupper":"432.00","totalTradedValue":"18,031.97","faceValue":"10.00","ndStartDate":"-","previousClose":"392.75","symbol":"TATASTEEL","varMargin":"11.84","lastPrice":"385.00","pChange":"-1.97","adhocMargin":"-","companyName":"Tata Steel Limited","averagePrice":"386.94","secDate":"18NOV2016","series":"EQ","isinCode":"INE081A01012","indexVar":"-","pricebandlower":"353.50","totalBuyQuantity":"403","high52":"441.50","purpose":"ANNUAL GENERAL MEETING\/DIVIDEND RS 8\/- PER SHARE","cm_adj_low_dt":"12-FEB-16","closePrice":"385.10","isExDateFlag":false,"recordDate":"-","cm_adj_high_dt":"11-NOV-16","totalSellQuantity":"-","dayHigh":"412.40","exDate":"28-JUL-16","sellQuantity5":"-","bcEndDate":"12-AUG-16","css_status_desc":"Listed","ndEndDate":"-","sellQuantity2":"-","sellQuantity1":"-","buyPrice1":"385.10","sellQuantity4":"-","buyPrice2":"-","sellQuantity3":"-","applicableMargin":"16.84","buyPrice4":"-","buyPrice3":"-","buyPrice5":"-","dayLow":"381.25","deliveryToTradedQuantity":"9.71","totalTradedVolume":"46,60,147"}],"optLink":"\/marketinfo\/sym_map\/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=TATASTEEL&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2"}
```

[Screenshot to better illustrate the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4pC6.png)

Answer (score 0):

on jquery use getJSON

```
    $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

read documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/